# joining 2 tables - result different as desired

Tags: mysql, sql, join

So here I am again. I have 2 tables:

ci_products:

[image]

ci_prodimages:

http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/8672/kv3b.png

I have a SQL query with join and `GROUP_CONCAT`.

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(img_url) urls FROM (`ci_products`) 
JOIN `ci_prodimages` ON `ci_prodimages`.`img_pid`=`ci_products`.`prod_id` 
WHERE `prod_cat` = '4' OR `prod_cat` = '8' OR `prod_cat` = '9' OR `prod_cat` = '10'
```

This SQL should return all 3 products. But it only returns the one with `prod_cat - 10`. Everything else is working but this.

Also this query:

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(img_url) urls FROM (`ci_products`) 
JOIN `ci_prodimages` ON `ci_prodimages`.`img_pid`=`ci_products`.`prod_id` 
WHERE `prod_cat` = '9'
```

Results in null result.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why should that return all three products? You limit the join to prod_id==1 because the is only one img_id.

Comment: well so how can I change it to retunr all 3 products ?

Comment: Is your intent to return all products regardless of whether there are images associated with it?

Comment: There will be always image associated with it. I want to return all products depends on URL - which you can see in WHERE/OR statement. and I want to return also images to products

Comment: Well, in the example there are no images associated with products 5 & 6.

Comment: Ah, I have forgot to add it there. I ahve add it there now and the result is still the same. also more: I get strange result of group_concat() - I get there all urls even if the product doesnt have all images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `GROUP_CONCAT` which is an aggregate function, but not using GROUP BY. MySQL does allow implicit grouping, where you can
select columns that are neither in a group by or an aggregate, but as you have seen you can run into problems. I would also not recommend using SELECT *, 
so your query would be better written as:

```
SELECT  p.prod_id, 
        p.Prod_Name, 
        p.prod_desc, 
        p.prod_nem, 
        p.prod_cat, 
        p.prod_minpric,
        p.prd_minbid,
        p.prod_marks,
        p.prod_added, GROUP_CONCAT(img_url) urls 
FROM    `ci_products` p
        JOIN `ci_prodimages` i
            ON p.`img_pid`= i.`prod_id` 
WHERE   `prod_cat` = '9'
GROUP BY p.prod_id, p.Prod_Name, p.prod_desc, p.prod_nem, p.prod_cat, p.prod_minpric, p.prd_minbid, p.prod_marks, p.prod_added
```

In MySQL (and according to the SQL-Standard) the following is also legal:

```
SELECT  p.prod_id, 
        p.Prod_Name, 
        p.prod_desc, 
        p.prod_nem, 
        p.prod_cat, 
        p.prod_minpric,
        p.prd_minbid,
        p.prod_marks,
        p.prod_added, GROUP_CONCAT(img_url) urls 
FROM    `ci_products` p
        JOIN `ci_prodimages` i
            ON p.`img_pid`= i.`prod_id` 
WHERE   `prod_cat` = '9'
GROUP BY p.prod_id;
```

Since `prod_id` is the primary key of the table `ci_products` it is not necessary to group by all columns since they are functionally dependant on the primary key, however, MySQL does not strictly enforce this standard which can lead to unexpected behaviour, so I would still recommend explicitly listing all columns that you are grouping by.

Below is a standard explanation I have previously written to explain how MySQL implicit grouping works, and why I avoid it:

---

I would advise to avoid the implicit grouping offered by MySQL where possible, by this i mean including columns in the select list, even though they are not contained in an aggregate function or the group by clause.

Imagine the following simple table (T):

```
ID  | Column1 | Column2  |
----|---------+----------|
1   |    A    |    X     |
2   |    A    |    Y     |
```

In MySQL you can write

```
SELECT  ID, Column1, Column2
FROM    T
GROUP BY Column1;
```

This actually breaks the SQL Standard, but it works in MySQL, however the trouble is it is non-deterministic, the result:

```
ID  | Column1 | Column2  |
----|---------+----------|
1   |    A    |    X     |
```

Is no more or less correct than

```
ID  | Column1 | Column2  |  
----|---------+----------|
2   |    A    |    Y     |
```

So what you are saying is give me one row for each distinct value of `Column1`, which both results sets satisfy, so how do you know which one you will get? Well you don't, it seems to be a fairly popular misconception that you can add and `ORDER BY` clause to influence the results, so for example the following query:

```
SELECT  ID, Column1, Column2
FROM    T
GROUP BY Column1
ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

Would ensure that you get the following result:

```
ID  | Column1 | Column2  |  
----|---------+----------|
2   |    A    |    Y     |
```

because of the `ORDER BY ID DESC`, however this is not true ([as demonstrated here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b917/1)).

The [MySQL documents](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) state:

> The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause.

So even though you have an order by this does not apply until after one row per group has been selected, and this one row is non-determistic.

The SQL-Standard does allow columns in the select list not contained in the GROUP BY or an aggregate function, however these columns must be functionally dependant on a column in the GROUP BY. For example, ID in the sample table is the PRIMARY KEY, so we know it is unique in the table, so the following query conforms to the SQL standard and would run in MySQL and fail in many DBMS currently (At the time of writing Postgresql is the closest DBMS I know of to correctly implementing the standard):

```
SELECT  ID, Column1, Column2
FROM    T
GROUP BY ID;
```

Since ID is unique for each row, there can only be one value of `Column1` for each ID, one value of `Column2` there is no ambiguity about what to return for each row.

Comment: Adding the group_by solved everything. Thanks a lot for making it clear

Answer (score 0):

An `inner join` only returns rows with matches in both tables:

```
FROM ci_products p
JOIN ci_prodimages i ON i.img_pid = p.prod_id
```

Try a `left join` instead, which returns all entries from the left hand table:

```
FROM ci_products p
LEFT JOIN ci_prodimages i ON i.img_pid = p.prod_id
```